# Difference between a positive and negative adjustable voltage regulator (LDO's)

Tags: electrical-engineering, circuit-design

I am having trouble understanding the difference between positive and negative adjustable voltage regulators (LDO's). There are circuit diagrams for the positive LDO's such as the following: [image]

I am not able to understand what a circuit diagram of a negative voltage regulator looks like or how different it would be from a positive voltage regulator.